# How to Fill combobox with A to Z automatically

Tags: vb.net

I want to know how to fill Combo Box English character "A" to "Z" programmatically. I try following way. I think there will be more easy way to do that job.

```
Combo1.Items.add("A")
Combo1.Items.add("B")
Combo1.Items.add("C")
Combo1.Items.add("D")
Combo1.Items.add("E")
Combo1.Items.add("F")
Combo1.Items.add("G")
Combo1.Items.add("H")
```

Comment: You can replace with a ascii number loop , but if thst is easier ...

Comment: I'm on trying that way. nbk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Given**: A ComboBox named *ComboBox1* exists.

Here are two options:

**Option 1**:

```
For i As Integer = 65 To 90
    ComboBox1.Items.Add(Chr(i))
Next
```

**Option 2**:

```
Dim ucAlphabet As String = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

For Each c As Char In ucAlphabet
    ComboBox1.Items.Add(c)
Next
```

**Note**: If one would like to add each letter as a *String*, instead of a *Char*, one can use [ToString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.tostring?view=net-7.0).

**Resources**:

- [ASCII Table](https://www.asciitable.com/)
- [Chr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.chr?view=net-7.0)

Comment: Thank You Very Much. Tu deschizi eu inchid

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer by *Tu deschizi eu inchid* is not wrong but I would tend to be more explicit and self-documenting. One could do this:

```vb
For i = Convert.ToInt32("A"c) To Convert.ToInt32("Z"c)
    ComboBox1.Items.Add(Convert.ToChar(i))
Next
```

but I would prefer one of these:

```vb
Dim alphabet = Enumerable.Range(Convert.ToInt32("A"c), 26).
                          Select(Function(i) Convert.ToChar(i)).
                          Cast(Of Object)().
                          ToArray()

ComboBox1.Items.AddRange(alphabet)
```

```vb
Dim alphabet = Enumerable.Range(Convert.ToInt32("A"c), 26).
                          Select(Function(i) Convert.ToChar(i)).
                          ToArray()

ComboBox1.DataSource = alphabet
```

The main practical difference in those two is that the second one will select the first item in the list by default where the first will not select an item at all.

Note that `Convert.ToInt32` and `Convert.ToChar` deal specifically with Unicode characters, much like `AscW` and `ChrW`, where `Asc` and `Chr` work with ASCII characters. It's generally not a big deal but you should really avoid those old VB Runtime functions that are holdovers from VB6 unless they actually add some value, which they rarely do.

Comment: all that is not valid with strict on,

Comment: i have tested it and my vs 2022 throws an error, as all m,y programs have by default STRICT ON, which doesn't allow such constructs, i discussed this with microsoft over and over again with LINQ and others

Comment: @nbk, I think that you almost certainly have `Option Infer Off`. This code relies on type inference for the `i` and `alphabet` variables - because why would you not. If you disable type inference then you would need to specify the types of those variables with `As Integer` and `As Object()` respectively. If you don't then, for `alphabet` at least, you'll get a message that tells you that `Option Strict On` requires an `As` clause. Given that `Option Infer` is `On` by default, you must have turned it `Off` so this is your doing. I assume that you'll be retracting that down vote now.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a program to generate the quoted letters with commas and then just

```
ComboBox1.Items.AddRange({"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"})
```

The "Remarks" section of the documentation for [`AddRange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.objectcollection.addrange) states:

> When using this method to add items to the collection, you do not need to call the BeginUpdate and EndUpdate methods to optimize performance.

You might want to do the latter if using repeated calls to `.Add`.